# Changing the background color of a window when the popup opens up in android studio

Tags: android

I have my popup window that opens up on an activity. I want to change the color of a main window. How can I do it to get the same effect as we get when the dialog window opens up.

Comment: Use a dialog like style for your activity.

Comment: I didnot get you. You mean to set the dialog theme to the popup?

Comment: I have set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" for the xml file of my popup. It does not work.